# same structure but different meaning

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, adjectives

I was reading a book about ww2 and i am in doubt about two terms:

Nazi Hunters : about people that tracks down Nazi after ww2

Nazi Killers :  used to refer the actual nazi in some parts

So in the first **Nazi** is like an adjective, in the second looks like it is **Killers**. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have compound nouns like *Nazi-hunter*, what you have is a noun–noun compound. There is likely an implied connecting preposition between them, such as *for* or *of* or *with*.

This is the same difference as found in *running shoes* versus *running water*, where the first uses *running* as a noun (those shoes are **for** running) while the second uses it as an adjective (the water **is** running).

Same thing with your pair.

In the *Nazi hunters* case, the word *Nazi* is being used as an attributive noun, the same way *baby* is in *baby sitter* or *pencil* is in *pencil sharpener*. These are about hunting Nazis, sitting babies, or sharpening pencils. The relationship is more like *hunters **of** Nazis*.

It is not being used as an adjective because if it were, then we would be able to say that the hunters *were* Nazis — buy you can't. They are not Nazis. They hunt Nazis.  In the same way, you cannot say that the sitter *is* a baby.

When you have killers who happen to **be** Nazis, then *Nazi* is working more like an adjective. Look for an "is a" relationship in adjective–noun compounds. The noun **is** an adjective. You can’t do that with noun–noun compounds.

In speech, you can usually hear which type it is because of the stress. A *BABY sitter* is stressed on that first word, a noun. With a *baby SEAL*, then the adjective isn’t usually stressed.

With *Nazi killers* you could have it either way, either *Nazi KILLERS* for killers who **are** Nazis or *NAZI killers* for killers **of** Nazis.